# What does animatableData in SwiftUI do?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui, core-animation

I was playing around with the `animatableData` property for a custom Shape I made but I couldn't really visualise what it does and where the system uses it.

I didn't understand how the system knows which `animatableData` properties it should interpolate when there's a state change. I also didn't understand what the `get` part of the `animatableData` property is used for by the system. The only thing I sort of understand is that SwiftUI will update the `animatableData` property to all the intermediary values between the original and final value for when an `@State` variable is changed.

If someone can give a very detailed order of events for the use of `animatableData` by the system I'll be extremely grateful. Make it as detailed as you can because I'm one of those people who feels scratchy even if I'm not understanding 1% of something (however if I do have any question I'll just ask you in the comments).

Thanks in advance!

*P.S. I tried returning a constant in the getter for `animatableData` and my animation still worked perfectly which has confused me even more. Please let me know what the getter is used for if you can.*

Comment: I am also such a person. Any answer?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer to your question is to override the default `animatableData` [inherited by the `Animatable` protocol] with values used to draw your View. Here's an example of how to do that:

```swift
    var animatableData: Double {
      get { return percent }
      set { percent = newValue }
   }
```

Here's an example for you. It:

- Draws a Ring on the parent View.

As the value of percent [which you hook up when you define
`animatableData`] changes, the animation updates the view by drawing a line along the circumference of the defined circle using the percent value at the time of the update.

[image: animating circle]

```
import SwiftUI

/// This repeats an animation until 5 seconds elapse
struct SimpleAnswer: View {
   /// the start/stop sentinel
   static var shouldAnimate = true
   /// the percentage of the circumference (arc) to draw
   @State var percent = 0.0

   /// animation duration/delay values
   var animationDuration: Double { return 1.0 }
   var animationDelay: Double { return  0.2 }
   var exitAnimationDuration: Double { return 0.3 }
   var finalAnimationDuration: Double { return 1.0 }
   var minAnimationInterval: Double { return 0.1 }

   var body: some View {
      ZStack {
         AnimatingOverlay(percent: percent)
            .stroke(Color.yellow, lineWidth: 8.0)
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
            .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
            .padding(20)
            .onAppear() {
               self.performAnimations()
            }
            .frame(width: 150, height: 150,
                   alignment: .center)
         Spacer()
      }
      .background(Color.blue)
      .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
   }

   func performAnimations() {
      run()
      if SimpleAnswer.shouldAnimate {
         restartAnimation()
      }
      /// Stop the Animation after 5 seconds
      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0, execute: { SimpleAnswer.shouldAnimate = false })
   }

   func run() {
      withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: animationDuration)) {
         percent = 1
      }
      let deadline: DispatchTime = .now() + animationDuration + animationDelay
      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadline) {
         withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: self.exitAnimationDuration)) {
         }
         withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: self.minAnimationInterval)) {
         }
      }
   }

   func restartAnimation() {
      let deadline: DispatchTime = .now() + 2 * animationDuration + finalAnimationDuration
      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadline) {
         self.percent = 0
         self.performAnimations()
      }
   }
}

/// Draws a Ring on the parent View
/// By default, `Shape` returns the instance of `EmptyAnimatableData` struct as its animatableData.
/// All you have to do is replace this default `EmptyAnimatableData` with a different value.
/// As the value of percent changes, the animation updates the view
struct AnimatingOverlay: Shape {
   var percent: Double

   func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
      let end = percent * 360
      var p = Path()

      p.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: rect.size.width/2, y: rect.size.width/2),
               radius: rect.size.width/2,
               startAngle: Angle(degrees: 0),
               endAngle: Angle(degrees: end),
               clockwise: false)
      return p
   }

   /// This example defines `percent` as the value to animate by
   /// overriding the value of `animatableData`
   /// inherited as Animatable.animatableData
   var animatableData: Double {
      get { return percent }
      set { percent = newValue }
   }
}

#if DEBUG
struct SimpleAnswer_Previews : PreviewProvider {
   static var previews: some View {
      SimpleAnswer()
   }
}
#endif
```

I found these links to help me answer your question. You should find them useful as well.

[Wenderlich - How to Create a Splash Screen With SwiftUI](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4503153-how-to-create-a-splash-screen-with-swiftui)

[Majid - The Magic of Animatable Values](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/06/17/the-magic-of-animatable-values-in-swiftui/)

[Animations in SwiftUI - Majid](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2019/06/26/animations-in-swiftui/)

Comment: How does SwiftUI "hook up" `animatableData` to the correct property?

Comment: You do this by defining how it "sets" the animatableData variable.  **You** hook it up by pointing it to a variable **you** have defined - in this case **percent**. The animatable protocol provides this hook - when you conform to it you are required to define what you want to change in your view - so the protocol defines that animatableData is updated, and you make sure that when animatableData is updated it updates your variable however you want it updated. Let me know if that clears things up.